# MYSQL attendance by attendance date

Tags: mysql, dynamic-pivot

I want to make an attendance system in mysql. like two different dates lets say. 2017-12-21 and 2017-12-23

if i have

my table test looks like this.
name date attendance comment

```
Person 1 2017-12-21 Yes comment
Person 1 2017-12-23 Yes comment
Person 2 2017-12-21 No  comment 
Person 2 2017-12-23 Yes comment
```

And the result i want is

```
-----2017-12-21----------------2017-12-23-----------
-----Person 1 Yes comment ---- Person 1 Yes comment
-----Person 2 NO  comment ---- Person 2 Yes comment
----------------------------------------------------
```

Think leftjoin will work but to hard for me someone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be an appeal to answer a homework or training problem. Please show any attempt in coding the process in order to get a response.

Comment: It is for a sports team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its for a sports team. I have this my database now i have tested many ways to do it. Group_Contact wont work.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
      `playerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `idnumber` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `date` date NOT NULL,
      `attendance` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `comment` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`playerid`)
);
```

This is the result i want use it in php later. (a = attendance c = comment)

```
attendance| Name     | a2017-12-21|c2017-12-21|a2017-12-23|c2017-12-23|

          | Person 1 |     YES    |   Comment |     NO    |  Comment  |

          | Person 2 |     YES    |   Comment |    YES    |  Comment  |
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about the exact format you expect. If your table structure looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `attendance` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

You can run the below query,

```
SELECT date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`name`, ' ', `attendance`, ' ', `comment`) AS attendance_info 
FROM `attendance`
GROUP BY `date`
```

to extract data in the below format.

```
date        | attendance_info

2017-12-21  | Person 1 YES Comment,Person 2 NO Comment

2017-12-23  | Person 1 YES Comment,Person 1 YES Comment
```